# ServiceStack and Facebook/Twitter authentication from an iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, servicestack

ServiceStack on my server has built in endpoints for /auth/facebook and /auth/twitter... but are these only useful when you are using a browser?... what about for an app?

I have an iOS app that utilizes the built in Facebook and Twitter accounts in the ACAccountStore object. With these objects I am ultimately able to call SLRequest.GetPreparedUrlRequest... from here I can extract the following:

Facebook: (from the request url) access_token

Twitter: (from the request header) oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_token, oauth_signature, and oauth_version

Can I use these somehow with auth/facebook or auth/twitter to sign in and even possibly register an account with the built-in functionality? It seems to me that these endpoints are for a browser. Is there some other way to do this... or should I just write my own endpoints to authenticate utilizing (for example in Facebook) the access_token and get user information on the server myself directly from the Facebook graph?

Comment: For those who are interested in how to get these credentials from the built-in ACAccountStore: The ACAccount object does not allow direct access to some of the credential information (Facebook is there, Twitter is not)... so the SLRequest.GetPreparedUrlRequest method generates a request for the respective service. This request includes authentication information... so I am able to extract the Facebook access_token from the url generated by this request. And I can extract the Twitter information from the request header value "Authorization" without having to make the actual request.

Comment: Additionally I can take the above twitter values and (client side) get back the following values if this helps: oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, user_id, and screen_name. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth)